HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=44931): Read timed out
I am trying to call gemini api and getting HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=44931): Read timed out. in google colab. If I run the function, it will show me the output but when I call via api endpoint it is timing out.
  try:
    response = model.generate_content([prompt, img])
    output = response.resolve()
  except Exception as error:
    print(error)

prompt is multiline commented big prompt with around 300 words. any clue?
